# render has doesn't have a good quality as preview

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

the rope texture is not showing well in the render, what is the problem?
[image]

heres the .blend file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/7orb65pyzrs6e3u/fuse.blend?dl=0

Comment: I just figured out that the motion blur was making the problem, but without it the sparks dont look good, is there a way that motion blur will affect one object? if not then how can I retain the ropes looks but still have the sparks?

Comment: If you want motion blur on a part of your image, you should probably make the sparks faster and your shutter speed slower. Alternatively, you can fake the effect by compositing two images together. Especially for sparks, this might be easy as you can probably just add them over the other image and will not have to worry about masks. If you mean what I think you mean when you write about sparks, that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way that motion blur will affect one object?

Yes. Disable *Motion Blur* in *Properties > Object*:

[image]

Now that object will not be affected:

[image]